# Array combines repeated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I've got the following array:

```
Object { id: "1", name: "a", hour: "08:00:00" }  
Object { id: "2", name: "b", hour: "08:00:00" }  
Object { id: "3", name: "c", hour: "08:00:00" }  
Object { id: "4", name: "d", hour: "07:15:00" }  
Object { id: "5", name: "e", hour: "08:00:00" }  
Object { id: "6", name: "f", hour: "08:00:00" }  
Object { id: "7", name: "g", hour: "09:00:00" }  
Object { id: "8", name: "h", hour: "08:30:00" }
```

And when I try to access the "**hour**" value by:

```
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var hour = array[i]['hour'];
    console.log(hour);
}
```

I get the following result:

```
08:00:00  (3 repeats) 
07:15:00   
08:00:00  (2 repeats) 
09:00:00   
08:30:00
```

How can I avoid that and get:

```
08:00:00  
08:00:00 
08:00:00 
07:15:00   
08:00:00
08:00:00  
09:00:00   
08:30:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing what browser is printing... You can't change this with js. It's a Browser dependent setting, in Chrome just enable timestamp to see each console.log in different lines.

[Chrome debugger - how to turn off console.log message grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706235/chrome-debugger-how-to-turn-off-console-log-message-grouping)

Comment: The problem is I use the value of "hour" to compare it with another value hold by "name" and what actually happens is that i compares the first 5 values with the values of the first output I've shown above. I am using Firefox.

Comment: In Firefx this method seems to not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991956/how-do-i-disable-firefox-console-from-grouping-duplicate-output probably you can try as suggested to add the print message to an object and to print the object at the end of the cycle

Answer (score 0):

That's browser specific. But you can do a workaround for this by saving your data in a variable where you seperate each line by a \n and make the output to the console at the end.

```
   var output='';
   for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var hour = array[i]['hour'];
        if (i) output +='\n';
        output += hour;
    }
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the [console has different methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) and usages.. but you can get the desired output in console by iterating over the array, using the index and calling a [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with the optional delay parameter `index * 200`:

```js
var array = [{ id: "1", name: "a", hour: "08:00:00" }  , { id: "2", name: "b", hour: "08:00:00" }  , { id: "3", name: "c", hour: "08:00:00" }  , { id: "4", name: "d", hour: "07:15:00" }  , { id: "5", name: "e", hour: "08:00:00" }  , { id: "6", name: "f", hour: "08:00:00" }  , { id: "7", name: "g", hour: "09:00:00" }  , { id: "8", name: "h", hour: "08:30:00" }];

array.forEach(function (elem, index) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(elem.hour);
  }, index * 200);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How can I store elem.hour in a separate variable for each element?

Comment: Array store values from the different elements.. You already had that information, and you can use it.. Don't see why you need those variables?

Comment: Because I need to use each one of these into another method.

Comment: In that method you can access them from the same `array` variable.. It already is a variable with all the `hour`s